# Nesting XML Tags using Linq with Data From DB

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to build an XML document using Linq, XElement and data from Database,

It's working kinda, but in my XML, I want to close the  tag and start a new tag  and get the results from the query to populate into for the  Tag, it is complaining that my variable r in the  tag is unresolved, how can I make this work, or is there a better way of building the XML. All the child elements should be under the parent , having two children  and , which has their own set of children.

Here is the code below

```
public void GenerateXML(int id, string site, string state, string country, string bFn, string bLn, string sFn, string sLn)
    {
        var results = (from o in _db.Orders
            where o.OrderId == id
            select o).ToList();


        var xmlDoc = new XElement("Order",
            from r in results
            select
            new XElement("OrderHeader",

                new XElement("SiteId", site),
                new XElement("OrderId", r.OrderId),
                new XElement("Time", r.OrderDate.Value),
                new XElement("Subtotal", r.SubTotal),
                new XElement("Shipping", ""),
                new XElement("SalesTax", r.SalesTax),
                new XElement("Total", r.Total),
                new XElement("PaymentAmount", ""),
                new XElement("PaymentMethod", ""),
                new XElement("ArchiTypeAcctNum", "20001"),
                new XElement("TaxExempt", r.TaxExempt), 
                new XElement("SpecialInstructions", r.SpecialInstructions),
                new XElement("BillTo",
                    new XElement("BillEmail", r.BillToEmail),
                    new XElement("FirstName", bFn),
                    new XElement("LastName", bLn),
                    new XElement("CompanyName", r.BillCompany),
                    new XElement("Address1", r.BillToAddress),
                    new XElement("City", r.BillToCity),
                    new XElement("State", state),
                    new XElement("Country", country),
                    new XElement("Zip", r.BillToZip),
                    new XElement("Phone", r.BillToPhoneNumber)),
                new XElement("ShipTo",
                    new XElement("FirstName", sFn),
                    new XElement("LastName", sLn),
                    new XElement("CompanyName", r.ShipCompany),
                    new XElement("Address1", r.ShipToAddress),
                    new XElement("City", r.ShipToCity),
                    new XElement("State", state),
                    new XElement("Country", country),
                    new XElement("Zip", r.ShipToZip),
                    new XElement("Phone", r.ShipToPhoneNumber))),
               new XElement("Items",
                from i in r.Items
                select new XElement("Item",
                    new XElement("SKU", i.SkuNumber),
                    new XElement("PROD_Name", i.ProductName),
                    new XElement("Description", i.Description),
                    new XElement("Attributes", i.Attributes),
                    new XElement("Quantity", i.Quantity),
                    new XElement("UnitPrice", i.UnitPrice),
                    new XElement("InkColor", i.InkColor)))              
                    );

        xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~/Xml/Orders.xml"));
        RedirectToAction("Save");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an extension for same purpose. I think much easier . you can just use as orders.EntityToXml();

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{


        public static bool EntityToXml<T>(this T entity, string filePath)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
            }

            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }

            var serializer= new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (var stream = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream , entity);
                return true;

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Haksu, I am kind of new to this, can you explain how to use this extension with my existing code, many thanks

Comment: If you don't know extension methods you can read this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: What code does serializes object as xml and writes to file.